# Sharing my message with share kit to twitter

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

i imported sharekit library in my project and i write following codes

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:@"sample message"];
SHKTwitter* twt = [[SHKTwitter alloc] init];
[twt setItem:item];
[twt share];
```

or

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:@"sample message"];
[SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
```

as you know, first authentication window appears. i want to share text when i enter my user name and password. but it redirect my redirect url and window don't close automatically

Comment: isn't there anyone who know this problemmmm :'( my brain will explode a few minute later :(

Comment: i figure out my problem. if you have problem like that, i can write my solition.